Using same Bedrock service with LLM
I have been thinking and reading on it, if I can use two separate databases by not compromising security in database with bedrock, RAG and LLM for example Anthropic Claude for Chatbot solution.
For example, I have two clients I want to use same backend for both clients by keeping database access separate for each client but in turn using Throughput provisioning of Claude Model.
